# Unhandled exception while using zlib uncompress()

Tags: c++, zlib, compression

I am having some problems performing uncompression with zlib uncompress() function. The file that I compressed, which is being passed as fileSource to uncompressFile(), didn't throw me a runtime exception and worked perfectly fine. What I am doing basically is reading the bytes from a file, with fread, and then storing it in a buffer and then compressing/decompressing.
   My uncompress function:

```
    bool unCompressFile(const char* fileSource, const char* fileDestination) {
        std::cout << "\nFilesize: " << fileSize << std::endl << "compressedSize: " << compressedSize << std::endl;
        // Test printout: fileSize = 164008 && compressedSize = 77778
        // These were the values from a test program
        char* bufferSource = new char[(sizeof(char) * compressedSize + 1)]; 
        if (!bufferSource) {
          std::cout << "Error allocating memory \n"; return false; 
        }
        // Reading from previously compressed file
        FILE* inputFile = NULL;
        inputFile = fopen(fileSource, "rb");
        if (!inputFile) { return false; } // Error handling

        if (!fread(bufferSource, compressedSize, 1, inputFile)) {
            fclose(inputFile);
            delete[] bufferSource;
            return false;
        }
        fclose(inputFile);

        uLong destinationLen = fileSize;
        Bytef* bufferDestination = new Bytef[fileSize + 1];
        int result = uncompress(bufferDestination, &destinationLen, (const Bytef*)bufferSource, compressedSize); // Here is the error

        fclose(outputFile);

        delete[] bufferSource;
        delete[] bufferDestination;

        return true;

    }
```

The string fileSource is the path to an already compressed file and fileDestination would be the output, which I use fwrite(omitted here). Both `compressedSize` and `fileSize` are global variables. The value of fileSize is the length in bytes of the original file and compressedSize is the size of the compressed data(modified by compress()). Exception occurs at the uncompress function else no error print shows up. I can't see what is causing this runtime error.

**EDIT 1:** I tried with compress2(), and for the compression level I tried 0 (none) so basically with no compression and my unCompressFile function did work. Something is messing up the decompression but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT 2:** First 30 bytes of the compressed file:

```
78 9C EC B9 77 54 53 4D F4 2E 7C D2 03 84 10 31 90 84 1A A4 2B 1D 04 14 84 D0 51 EA 2B 55
```

Comment: *I can't see what is causing this runtime error.* -- Yes you can.  Zlib comes with full source code.  You should debug it.

Comment: I agree, but maybe is it possible that somehow the compressed data got corrupted and so this uncompress fails, I will have to check that.

Comment: You need to add an example of the first 30 bytes of so of compressed data in hex or base64, so we can determine if uncompress should be expected to be able to decompress it.

Comment: @MarkAdler Added the 30 bytes in hex of the compressed file.

Comment: That is a zlib stream, which is what `uncompress()` decompresses. Two things I would note. First: you are discarding the uncompressed data, never writing it to `outputFile`. Second: `uncompress()` does not throw any exceptions, unless the memory allocation functions (e.g. `malloc()`, `free()`) throw an exception. What makes you think "here is the error"?

Comment: @MarkAdler I didn't post the entire code (I omitted the part of writing the uncompressed buffer to outputFile). Maybe it was not the correct term, "here is the error", but I wanted to point out that the line that threw that exception was that one. I still couldn't figure out what the problem was through debugging.

Comment: How do you know that that's the line that threw the exception? What was the exception?

Comment: @MarkAdler Through the VisualStudio debugger, got the exeception  `Access violation reading location 0x002E1CB8.` In the uncompress() line

Comment: Just to check, please add this line to your code and report what was output: `cerr << "header: " << ZLIB_VERSION << ", library: " << zlibVersion() << endl;`

Comment: @MarkAdler `header: 1.2.11, library: 1.2.11`

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem. Your code works fine for me. Can you make the 77,778 bytes of compressed data available to download?

Comment: @MarkAdler http://ge.tt/4UvqdIo2 (77,778 bytes) The uncompressed file is the strings64.exe from windows sysinternal.

Comment: I have no problem with your code and your data. There's nothing more I can to to help. You'll need to debug this yourself.

Comment: @MarkAdler I'll have to do that, thanks anyways.

Comment: @MarkAdler Well the problem was that I was cmaking zlib with i686 asm implementation. I wonder why did the compress() function worked but the uncompress() didn't, (when I configured the .lib with `ASM686` option)

Comment: Ah. Those are third-party contributions to zlib and are not supported. Due to reported issues with both the compression and decompression assembler code, I plan to remove them from the contrib directory in the next version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable `ASM686` option to avoid this or other kind of errors when building zlib. As Mark Adler said:

> Those are third-party contributions to zlib and are not supported. Due
>   to reported issues with both the compression and decompression
>   assembler code, I plan to remove them from the contrib directory in
>   the next version.